# Calling getIntent Method in service

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I have to pass parameter from MyActivity.class to TestService.class. MyActivity is a Activity class and TestService is a Service that I have made for sending messages. I have to pass parameter from Activity to the Service, but when I call `Intent i = getIntent();` in service class, I am getting an error **getIntent() is undefined**.

So, how can I send parameters from my Activity to Service?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Start your service like this;

```
 Intent ir=new Intent(this, Service.class); 
 ir.putExtra("data", data); 
 this.startService(ir);
```

You attach your data as an intent extra.

Then to retrieve the data from the service;

```
data=(String) intent.getExtras().get("data");
```

So you can access your parameter from either the onHandleIntent or onStartCommand Intent parameter. (depending on which type of service you are running) For Example;

**Service**

```
protected void onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    data=(String) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
}
```

[public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29)

**IntentService**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    data=(String) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
}
```

[protected abstract void onHandleIntent (Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: and what it in case of system level services like accessibility that started its own?

Comment: What if I need to get the intent in the `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 2):

When you start Service with intent(having Data) then that intent is received in  method
`onStart(Intent intent, int startId)`
or

```
onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
this **intent** is your intent with data
}
```

of your Service.So receive your data from this method having intent as parameter