# The method getIntent() in undefined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, methods

I am making an app which has a switch on its main page and when the switch is on then it starts another activity . Here I am using getIntent() in the second activity . But it is not working and givivg the error "Undefined method" .I searched and found that this is due to the reason that my class extends 'service' and not 'activity' .But I still don't understand the solution.

```
public class OverlayButtonActivity extends Service implements OnTouchListener {
    Button mButton;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //mView = new HUDView(this);
         mButton = new Button(this);
         mButton.setText("Overlay button");
         mButton.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}
```

Any help??

Comment: See this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949248/calling-getintent-method-in-service?rq=1

Comment: if this is a service why are you trying to modify UI elemens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're doing an mistake by extending `Service` instead of `Activity`. Looking at your `class` name and your `onCreate` method, you're manipulating `View` elements, that cannot exists inside an `Android Service`.

The correct should be:

```
public class OverlayButtonActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I understood my mmistake . I have to make another class first which extends activity and that class should call getIntent() . I am going to try it.

Comment: then how send data from activity class to service class.

Beacon beacon = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(ListBeaconsActivity.EXTRAS_BEACON);
i getting error is "The method getIntent() is undefined for ServiceBackGround'"

Comment: @Prasad, you don't need to call `getIntent`, just override the `onStartCommand` method or the `onBind` and use the `Intent` argument instance.

Answer (score 0):

`Service`s are given an `Intent` in their `onStart` method, there is none available when you're in `onCreate`.