# how to pass value from activity to service?

Tags: android

I have written service as library project and connected that service to another application.now i want to pass some input values to service.how can I pass?

Pass values like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SelfMonitor.this, SchedulerService.class);
intent.putExtra("initialDelay", initialDelay);
intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime);
startService(intent);
```

Get value like this in service:

```
initialDelay = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("initialDelay"));
endTime = intent.getStringExtra("endTime");
```

but i am getting `null pointer` exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you do in your activites,

```
 Intent intent =  new Intent(Activity.this, YourService.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", value);
    startService(intent);
```

and in your service

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
value = extras.getString("key", "somestring");
}
```

For further details,please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949248/calling-getintent-method-in-service)

Comment: i cant able to use getIntent().getExtras(); in my service class oncreate method.

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949248/calling-getintent-method-in-service)

Comment: Pleasure was all mine

Answer (score 0):

```
You need serviceIntent for this purpose.

Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Activity.this, CheckAPI.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("number", "96999");
serviceIntent.putExtra("message", "hello world");         
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: how can fetch this two parameters in service class